# Unable to deploy project with Kingswaysoft 365 adapter to SSIS Catalog

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I have an SSIS project where I am using Kingswaysoft 365 adapter as the destination in a package. It has a simple OLEDB to CRM dataflow task.The package works as expected in SSDT. However, when I try to deploy the project to SSIS catalog, I get this error: 
*Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '45'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27203)*

When I checked SSISDB, The error message is:
*Failed to deploy the project. Fix the problems and try again later.:Unable to create the type with the name 'DynamicsCRM'.*

We have applied a perpetual license.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that you don't have our software installed on the server where the SSIS package is going to be deployed. Can you please verify this?

Comment: Thank you guys. This fixed it. We had to install the components on the server. Of course licence it afterwards.

Comment: Which software or components can you please mention the name ?